# Xamarin Android: center not working for textview

Tags: android, xamarin.android

i'm trying to make textView1 center with no luck  , tried with gravity center not sure if i'm getting the point wrongly here , i will be glad if you can clarify here as well so it would be good lesson for future , thank you in advance ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView
                android:text="  Number 1  "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />
            <EditText
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
            <TextView
                android:text="  Number 2  "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/textView2" />
            <EditText
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9sWw.png)

Comment: When you say centered, what do you mean exactly? Centered vertically? Perhaps you could attach an image (or a sketch) of what you would like the layout to look like.

Comment: This looks like Xamarin Android, not Xamarin Forms

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the layout weights wrong and this is probably causing your issue.

Try this:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:weightSum="2">
        <TextView
            android:text="  Number 1  "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"                 
            android:textAlignment="center"/>
        <EditText
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

This will make the `TextView` and `EditText` equal widths and center align the text in the `TextView`. Maybe you should read up on `layout_weight` to get a better understanding of how to use this. The parent should always have a weight sum, you then assign a weight to the children of this and set either the height or width of the children to 0 depending on what you want the weight to apply to. Hope that helps.